# Deploy model trained with custom loss function on Watson machine learning

Tags: keras, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I've trained a model on Watson Machine learning with a custom loss function but when I try to deploy it I get an error saying:

```
Invalid Input data: Unknow loss function:loss
```

I am aware that normally in Keras you can load a model that have custom loss function using:

```
load_model('model.h5', custom_object={'loss': loss_function})
```

I am now looking for a way to also add the definition of my loss function in my deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from official support:

Custom functions and layers for Keras aren't currently supported in WML. You can refer to what is supported in this dock: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/pm_service_supported_frameworks.html?audience=wdp&context=analytics It seems the part about loss functions is not mentioned here. We will update the documentation.

Date: `2019-01-28`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow the method described in this doc for `Custom Compnents in TF Models` for WML

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml-custom_libs_tensorflow.html?audience=wdp&context=analytics

the specific requirements are detailed here: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml-custom_libs_overview.html#requirements

The main idea is that you need to specify a runtime for your deployment *other thank the default runtime* and package up your custom component in the manner specified. Hope this helps.